# Calculating average of n consecutive minimum values in a column for a given condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to programming altogether, however my work assignments sometimes force me to automate some processes in Excel. Anyway, I wanted to calculate an average of n consecutive minimum values within a column for a given condition. I managed to find a code from user "Gary's Student" from July 2015, which fits just about perfect to my needs except I had to change Sums to Averages, however, since my programming skills are close to 0, I tried but hadn't succeeded to calculate those values for a given condition. For example (See picture in the following link.[Excel columns example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpUwD.jpg))in the column 2, the average of 3 consecutive minimum values is 44, however I'd like to add a condition for example, to calculate the average of 3 consecutive minimum values if the value/text in the first column is "B". The answer should obviously be 250.

Below is the initial VBA code:

```
    Public Function consec(rng As Range, x As Long) As Double
    Dim r As Range, i As Long, mymin As Double, temp As Double
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    i = 1
    Set r = rng(i).Resize(x, 1)
          mymin = wf.Average(r)
    For i = 2 To rng.Count - x + 1
        Set r = rng(i).Resize(x, 1)
        temp = wf.Average(r)
        If temp < mymin Then
        mymin = temp
        End If
    Next i
    consec = mymin
End Function
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The three lowest with B are 78,180,300 which the average is 186 not 250, unless I am missing something.

Comment: This can be done with a formula if you are interested.

Comment: @ScottCraner I guess I was miscalculating myself here in the first place. I am looking for consecutive values of the condition in column A, so the correct value should be an average of 300, 400 and 78 = 259.333. It is easy to see that from this example of 11 values, however I have some data that goes into thousands of values.

Answer (score 0):

To bypass vba the following array formula will achieve what you want:

```
=AVERAGE(SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$12=$E$1,$B$2:$B$12),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & E2))))
```

**Being an array formula it must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>** when exiting edit mode.  If done properly excel will put `{}` around the formula.

The `ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & E2))` part is what determines how many of the lowest amounts to average.  It iterates from `1` or the lowest to what ever value is in E2, in this case `3` or the third.

The IF() statement; `IF($A$2:$A$12=$E$1,$B$2:$B$12)` puts together an array of values that meet the criteria, In this case column A being equal to what is in E1 or 'B'.

The SMALL() function uses the array from the IF() and the Iteration from the first to get the smallest in the array and returns those values to the AVERAGE() Function.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your try, but as said in other comments, I am looking for an average of 3 consecutive minimum values in column B for type B. I managed to achieve that but without the condition in column A with the following array formula: MIN(AVERAGEIF(OFFSET($B$2;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(B2:B12)-2))-1;0;3);">0"))

Comment: The formula in my comment above answers only the question of the average of 3 consecutive minimum values, regardless of types in column A.